# Interaction between undo, save-excursion, delete-region

Tags: emacs, elisp, undo

Here are two commands to delete a sentence forward (without saving to the kill ring). The first is based on an example from EmacsWiki Elisp Cookbook, and the latter is like the former except that the call to save-excursion is in a different place.

```
;; good with undo
(defun my-test-1 ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (point)
                 (save-excursion
                   (forward-sentence 1)
                   (point))))

;; bad with undo
(defun my-test-2 ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (delete-region (point)
                   (progn
                     (forward-sentence 1)
                     (point)))))
```

When I run the first command and then undo it, point ends up in the right place, and that's not the case with the second command. Why does this difference happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `delete-region` records the point position at the time when the text was deleted in `buffer-undo-list` (see help for `buffer-undo-list`).

In `my-test-1` the construct `(save-excursion (forward-sentence 1) (point))` just returns the end of sentence position but does not move point in the scope of the `delete-region` command.

In `my-test-2` the point is moved to the end of sentence **when deletion takes place**. So, the end of sentence position is saved in `buffer-undo-list`. Only after that the old point position is restored.

Answer (score 2):

`save-excursion` saves (and tries to restore) only point, mark, and which buffer is current.  There is little sense in doing this around `delete-region`. Coded in C, `delete-region` does not keep track of anything, AFAIK.  Dunno just how `undo` handles its effects.

A general rule of thumb is to use `save-excursion` as locally as possible, to do what you need done. In this case, you only need `save-excursion` to hide the effects of `forward-sentence`, not the effects of `delete-region`.

This is probably only a partial explanation.  To see a bit more, you can do `M-x debug-on-entry my-test-N` and step through the debugger using `d` (and `c`).  That will help you understand just what is going on.